# PhpMyAdmin page problem

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost

I installed apache2, mysql, php, and phpmyadmin. Everything works well but  I got this problem in phpmyadmin and I can't understand why.

[image: Problem screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reconfigure phpmyadmin by doing the following

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

If that does not resolve the issue, purge phpmyadmin and reinstall phpmyadmin.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin
```

If still having issues. I recommend removing LAMP stack, and install using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Comment: It didn't work , i've already tried to reinstall phpmyadmin , but no succes

Comment: Updated my answer. It will download all dependencies, and I've only had to download additional PHP libs for certain web apps.